# Validate id number in php

Tags: php, regex, validation

The form of html format as shown as below:

```
 <tr style="height:15px;"><td></td></tr>
 <tr>
   <td>ID Card No<br /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input class="input" style="width:300" size="20" type="text" name="id" maxlength="5"/></td>
 </tr>
```

How can an id number (e.g. A1234) be validated in PHP format?

Comment: What do you mean "validated in PHP format" ? What do you want to validate it as? A phone number? A e-mail? What's the criteria for being validated?

Comment: Need more information for your question? Like what you have tried and what do you exactly want.

Comment: please elaborate your question.. how can you validate id field..

Comment: 1. Have validation rules (@Epodax comment) 2. Use `regular expressions` to apply those rules.

Comment: Using pattern="[A-Z]{1}\d{4}" inside the input tag,but this is html5 validation.

Comment: I have created a php include the text box like above code. The length of the id card number is set like A1234. I want to validate the id number like the first character is English letter (A-Z) and remain character is number (0-9).  Thanks your help

Comment: @user3056561 is my way is correct for you?

Comment: Jarachanthan Ratnakumar your way is incorrect as this is HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply regex to accept `one upper char and four digits` should be:

```
$str = 'A1234';
$result = preg_match('~^[A-Z]\d{4}$~', $str);
print_r($result); // true | false
```

Comment: I don't know the expreesion " $str = 'A1234';" mean

Comment: @user3056561: it's value from input you gave us in question. In real it will be `$_POST['id']` or `$_GET['id']`, depends of method attribute of the form (value of `<input name=id ...>`). First line will be `$str = $_GET/POST['id']`.

Comment: The regular expression is not work for me. Is that any other expreesion for reference?

Comment: @user3056561: it will work on server, it's PHP. In browser you need to use JS regex, with the same pattern. Be please more specific what `doesnt work for me` means.

Comment: Yes, I need to use JS regex. Thanks a lot